# Ratchet Websocket push integration

Tags: php, networking, websocket, ratchet

I am trying to develop a chat system using Websockets (Ratchet). Until now I have already made a functional PHP based Websocket server that is able to answer on predefined JSON encoded message using the following method.

```
function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg){ ... }
```

The problem is that I'd like to push messages from the backend database via a background worker/thread to the right client, if something changed in my tables. Is this possible using PHP?

I don't want the client asking the websocket server every 5 minutes to refresh its state as shown below.

```
{"action":"giveMeUpdates"}
```

but the webserver should be able to do something like this:

```
{"status":"newMessages", "messagelist":[...]}
```

In addition:

```
class Chat extends ChatActionHandler implements MessageComponentInterface { ... }
```

this is my class where the ChatActionHandler holds functions for interacting with client requests. With the MessageComponentInterface i can only reply on Socket events like `function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)`. It is runned by the RatchetIO Server:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
   new Chat(),
   8080);
$server->run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach timer, like cron with

```
$this->loop->addPeriodicTimer($timeout, function($timer) {});
```

Comment: The MessageComponentInterface does not hold such a function. Do you mean the  \React\EventLoop\LoopInterface? I think i might have to instantiate it first somewhere in my constructor for the Chat class right?